# Checkbox - como verificar se ao menos 1 cbx foi selecionada

Tags: java, android, checkbox

Olá,
Tenho um conjunto de 8 checkBoxs. Alguém sabe como eu verifico se pelo menos 1 deles foi selecionado?
Obrigada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se quiser testar um-a-um:

```
boolean algumSelecionado = jcbx1.isSelected() || jcbx2.isSelected() || jcbx3.isSelected() || jcbx4.isSelected()
                        || jcbx5.isSelected() || jcbx6.isSelected() || jcbx7.isSelected() || jcbx8.isSelected();
```

Ou um solução mais dinâmica se os JCheckBox estiverem dentro de um JPanel:

```
boolean algumSelecionado = false;

for (Component c : jpnl.getComponents()) {
  if (c instanceof JCheckBox && ((JCheckBox) c).isSelected()) {
    algumSelecionado = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Simples e Genial! Valeu! Só troquei o .isSelected por .isChecked.

Comment: @ElaineBredaSchwaner não é `swing`? Tem que ver se a segunda opção que eu coloquei funciona então

Comment: Não sei o que é swing. Mas está funcionando, maravilha!

Answer (score 1):

```
CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
checkBox1.isChecked();
```

Comment: Obrigada. Juntei sua resposta com o do colega e deu tudo maravilha.